# Cannot set Outlook '13 as default mail client in Win10: "Either there is no default mail client or..."

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2013

Very aggravating issue on my work machine (Dell Optiplex 5050 - Windows 10 Enterprise x64, build 1803 - Spring Creators Update).

Every time I click as .MSG file I get this error:
`Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.`

Outlook already *is* the default email program. Any ideas how to fix this? If it matters, our email server is Exchange 2007.

UPDATE: I have now tried a repair install of Office Pro '13 and deleting this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail\Microsoft Outlook` (via MS instructions, albeit very old ones: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813745/either-there-is-no-default-mail-client-or-the-current-mail-client-cann). Neither made a difference.

Comment: When did this problem start?

Comment: It's been happening for months, not exactly sure.

Comment: See if anything here helps....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2f1b1212-155c-4eb2-aad6-73c167a180e9/not-able-to-open-msg-files-saved-with-outlook-2016?forum=outlook

Comment: Did you try to associate it by [file type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs)?

Comment: @spike_66, yes, it does not help.

Comment: Have you tried repairing Office 2013 via Control Panel and check if it helps?

Comment: Yes, I have tried repairing Office 2013. It did not help.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, this worked! Thanks very much. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. I checked any/all keys inside "PreviewHandlers" folders (I don't have click-to-run, but the other 2 were there) and deleted any/all references to IMAP, mail, email, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup these registry keys with an export first, and then any keys labeled "**Microsoft Windows MAPI Preview Handler**" *delete all or any that may exist* in your environment. After this you should reboot the machine immediately before testing just to be thorough.

> 1. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers`
> 2. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers`
> 3. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers`
>
> <sub>[Source Idea](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/outlook-2016-error-mesage-either-there-is-no/12b3504e-a4ee-40e4-8b92-6ce7e61f8cc5)</sub>

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- > I checked any/all keys inside "PreviewHandlers" registry folders (I
  >   don't have click-to-run, but the other 2 were there) and deleted
  >   any/all *keys that referenced IMAP, mail, email, etc. I did not delete
  >   the "PreviewHandlers" registry folders themselves. –
  >   [SamAndrew81](https://superuser.com/users/580262/samandrew81)
- [Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfil the messaging request. Please run outlook and set it as the default mail client](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/outlook-2016-error-mesage-either-there-is-no/12b3504e-a4ee-40e4-8b92-6ce7e61f8cc5)
- ["This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it" error ~](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3100511/this-file-cannot-be-previewed-because-there-is-no-previewer-installed)

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/outlook-2016-error-mesage-either-there-is-no/12b3504e-a4ee-40e4-8b92-6ce7e61f8cc5

Comment: I didnt require a restart. Just deleted the key and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft Support article pertains to Outlook 2013 and may
explain the problem
[Can't preview .msg files in Windows File Explorer with 64-bit Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3189902/can-t-preview-msg-files-in-windows-file-explorer-with-64-bit-outlook) :

> This issue occurs when you have the 64-bit version of Microsoft Outlook installed. The Windows preview host requires a 32-bit application previewer. When 32-bit Outlook is installed, it acts as the previewer. Without 32-bit Outlook installed, there is no previewer available for .msg files.

Two solutions are recommended for this problem :

> **Method 1: Disable the Windows Explorer Preview Pane, and open the .msg file to view it in Outlook**
>
> - Open Windows File Explorer.
> - On the View tab, click Preview pane to disable it.
> - To view the .msg file, double-click it to open it in Outlook.
>
> **Method 2: Use 32-bit Outlook**
>
> If you prefer to preview .msg files in Windows File Explorer, install
>   the 32-bit version of Outlook instead of the 64-bit version.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed my issue exactly. Thank you! While I hate that I can't use preview (I am not switching to 32-bit Outlook) it is nice to know what causes this. I'll just turn off the preview pane when I need to work with .MSG files.

Comment: Ok, so this _identifies_ my issue, but does not resolve it. Disabling the preview pane or switching to Outlook 32-bit are workarounds, not resolutions.